# Unable to create default domain for integrated weblogic server in jdeveloper

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

When i try to start the integrated weblogic server in jdeveloper i am getting error..Creating default domain failed..

When i try to start it from cmd i am able to start after adding the line

os.putenv('ADRS_DOMAIN_PASSWORD', 'welcome1')

in CreateDefaultDomain.py. but from jdeveloper i am not able to start..Because,each time the file CreateDefaultDomain.py is getting created when i try to start from jdev and it doesn't have the line i mentioned above..

Please help me how to solve this issue...I tried all workarounds i know..Its not helping..

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your SystemXXX folder (e.g. C:\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.4.39.64.36.1)  and Jdeveloper will try to reconfigure everything again at next Jdeveloper start.

This is a folder used internally by Jdeveloper instance.